# VBO for tilemap (draw order and slanted aerial 2D)

Tags: c, opengl, vbo

I want to draw a tilemap in a (ANSI C, C99 cannot be used due to windows compatibility) game that uses GL for accelerated graphics, although the game is a top-down 2D perspective using textured quads.
The popular opinion for handling a timemap seems to use a GL vertex buffer object, which I am about to write. However, I realized I want some tiles to go a little beyond vertical bounds, faking a slanted aerial view. That will make whatever is directly above the block to be partially covered by the tile.
If I use a VBO here, I will need to draw the entire tilemap in one sitting. Meaning that any object I draw afterwards will be directly on top of the tilemap.

What would be the sanest approach to this problem? Should I draw the tilemap first, then the entities (players/enemies) and then the excess vertical space so they cover the entities, and finally the effects that display over both? (such as shots, explosions, etcetera). But this would give me the issue of shots not being covered by terrain, and if I change the order, terrain covering large explosions awkwardly.
Alternatively I can sort all visual objects and draw them in a top-down fashion, but that would mean I need to change textures often, as sorting by texture wouldn't help too much in this specific case.

As well, I want to be able to modify the colors of every individual vertex in the grid in a dynamic way, so that entities can cast colors into the map. From what I am understanding, the way to achieve this would be with a vertex shader. Is this correct?

EDIT: A last thing. If I draw a VBO like that tilemap that is larger than the screen,by translating,  does GL automatically cull out-of-view faces or do I need to reform the VBO every time I move the "camera"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VBO is just a piece of abstract memory reserved in the graphics memory. You can place data in any layout and arrangement as you like. You can use a single VBO to store several independent meshes. *gl{Vertex,Normal,TexCoord,Color,Attrib}Pointer* functions are used to set the offset into memory, that means either process address space or offset into the bound VBO.

Furthermore once can easily draw only subsets of the bound data with either *glDrawArrays* and *glDrawElements* by choosing approriate first element or indices in the index buffer.

So, no, you don't have to draw entire VBOs.

Answer (score 0):

I actually answered my own question. I needed to separate the map in two: blocks that have empty space directly on top, and then the rest. Effects will be drawn in two passes, "regular" and "top" "layer"

I feel pretty bad about having an useless question lying around though, so if some admin needs to purge it, please go ahead.